# Arranging Integers using Conditional statements

Tags: python

I was wondering if someone would be able to help me regarding my coding problem. I'm still a beginner and I may have missed something here.

Basically, the instruction says that I need to arrange 3 integers in ascending order.
e.g Input : 5 2 4 ------> Output : 2 4 5

I need to utilize the conditional statements for this. Here is what I've done so far.

```
a, b, c = input().split()
a = int (a)
b = int (b)
c = int (c)

if a < b and a < c:
   smallest = a
elif b < a and b < c:
   smallest = b
else:
   smallest = c

if a > b and a < c:
   middle = a
elif a < b and a > c:
   middle = a
elif b > a and b < c:
   middle = b
elif b < a and b > c:
   middle = b
else:
   middle = c


if a > b and a > c:
   largest = a
elif b > a and b > c:
   largest = b
else:
   largest = c

print(smallest, middle, largest)
```

This is on CodeChum btw, I'm stuck in this because I can't figure out why it doesn't accept the code I did. Basically there are 5 tests that the code needs in order to submit the whole activity. I managed to do test 1-4 but for some reason it fails on test 5.

Comment: For reference, the sane code would be `smallest, middle, largest = sorted([a, b, c])`…

Comment: ``1 1 2`` returns ``2 2 2``, I think the test failed when two numbers were the same.

Comment: What happens if two of the input numbers are equal?

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't thought of that. Maybe that really is the problem. I'll be working on it again tomorrow thank you for replying.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code does not react well if two numbers are identical. You should replace your strict inequalities with non-strict ones.

---

```
a = 3
b = 3
c = 1

if a > b and a < c:
   middle = a
elif a < b and a > c:
   middle = a
elif b > a and b < c:
   middle = b
elif b < a and b > c:
   middle = b
else:
   middle = c
   
print(middle) # 1 when it should be 3
```

As `a == b`, none of the 4 conditions can be True, and therefore the middle number will always be `c`.

---

In order to support the case where `a == b`, we can add another condition:

```
elif a == b:
    middle = a
else:
    middle = c
```

we can simplify this code by replacing the strict inequalities with non-strict ones (`⩽` , `<=` in Python):

```
if b <= a < c:
    middle = a
elif b >= a > c:
    middle = a
elif a < b < c:
    middle = b
elif a > b > c:
    middle = b
else:
    middle = c
```

We simply said that if `a == b`, the middle is always `a`. I also simplified the structure for better readability.

Comment: Another solution could be to remove the `else` block and replace it with an `elif` block.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you elaborate further on "strict" and "non-strict" inequalities? I don't know the terms, tried searching online but didn't get what exactly it is. The replies above also says that the problem is when the inputs are equal, i'm planning to insert another elif which is for the numbers that are the same. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I did try removing else, and just leaving it on the very last part of the code for middle but it failed all the tests. I might be doing it wrong tho.

Comment: @schwein I tried to elaborate my comment

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use `sorted` function?

This one results in the exact thing you are looking for.

```py
smallest, middle, largest = sorted(map(int, input().split()))
print(smallest, middle, largest)
```

Note that you don't need the `map` to `int` function for this. But you if don't do that, the `smallest, middle, largest` variables will remain `str` objects.

Comment: Probably because *not* doing that is a requirement? (Like most exercises, the point is not to produce a particular output but to practice particular concepts - in this case, conditionals and logic.)

Comment: Meh, so much code :-P Try ``print(*sorted(input().split(), key=int))``

Comment: @KellyBundy I thought maybe he needs the variables. I tried to keep the structure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I cannot use that since it won't pass the activity if I don't use a conditional statement.

Comment: @schwein Then just add one. Like `if False: silly_requirement`.

Comment: I wish it was that easy, maybe it is? Idk lol I seriously don't know what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

As the input is guaranteed to contain exactly 3 numbers (separated by whitespace) you can just do this:

```
if (inval := input()):
    if len(nums := inval.split()) == 3:
        try:
            lo, mid, hi = sorted(map(int, nums))
            print(lo, mid, hi)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Comment: I would love to use that but it doesn't pass it unless it is made using a conditional statement

Comment: What conditional statement is needed? What do you need to check? Do you need to validate the input perhaps? There's certainly no attempt at validation in your code!

Comment: it just revolves around if-elif-else statements, I haven't really tried the other ones because it wasn't on the topic and because my knowledge is still shallow. I need to find the problem on the code that I did

Comment: It might have something to do with 2 inputs being the same, as stated by the others.

Comment: Validation? I'm really sorry I don't have any idea what means in terms of coding. Do I really need to validate it? Excuse my ignorance. I mean it's just an activity in our school in  the website codechum

Comment: Validation means **EVERYTHING** when writing computer programs. Also, I've edited the code to include some *if* statements just because you seem to want them

Comment: Thanks for your insights, I still have so much to learn